# JEST: select an HTML element through innerHTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

Folks, I have a React Component which on rendering has this HTML in it:

```
<button class="encryped-class__2TKgPzyme4 encryped-class__1ZnNbe3gTn">1</button>
```

It's a pagination button, and I want to simulate a click on it. The hacky way to select this element was:

```
const wrapper = Enzyme.mount(<Component {...someDefaultProps} />);
wrapper.find("button.encryped-class__2TKgPzyme4")
    .first()
    .simulate("click");
```

I want to select this with the innerHTML value being `1`.

Is there a way I can do that? If not, is there an alternate way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try the [findWhere](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/findWhere.html) method:

```
const wrapper = Enzyme.mount(<Component {...someDefaultProps} />);
wrapper.findWhere(x => x.text() === '1')
  .first()
  .simulate("click");
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!